# Sort integers in array/list then print them out in particular order in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

here is my code:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] numbers = {9, 5};

        if (numbers[0] > numbers[1]){
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        }else if (numbers[1] > numbers[0]) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        }
    }
}
```

so far i have this code where it grabs the numbers and then prints them out. obviously it will always do the if statement. is there a way where you can say do something like below:

```
if (numbers[0] > numbers[1]){
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numbers(1, 0));
            }else if (numbers[1] > numbers[0]){
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numbers(1, 0));
            }
```

where 0 and 1 are positions in the array. also is `System.out.print(numbers[0]);` valid syntax or how can i get it doing this thus avoiding converting toString() stage

thanks

p.s. very new to java hence simpleness, also NOTE: trying to not sure built-in functions like .sort() because that defeats the point of the exercise.

Comment: You want to *sort* the list? You can convert the array to a `List`, use `sort` and convert it back to array.

Comment: You're not really sorting the array, you're just checking the first two elements. You're also doing the exact same thing in both branches of the if statement, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish there.

Comment: 1) sorry im trying not to use built in functions and 2) i agree @NikG but the if blocks are different to see what i am trying to go for

Comment: which numnuts downvoted my question or put it in hold, i have a solution now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Or this:

```
public static void exchangeSort ( int [ ] num ) {
     int i, j, temp;
     for ( i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i ++ ) {
          for ( j = i + 1; j < num.length; j ++ ){
               if( num[ i ] < num[ j ] ){
                       temp = num[ i ]; 
                       num[ i ] = num[ j ];
                       num[ j ] = temp; 
                }           
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: as simple as it can get

Comment: oh yeh i should have said, im trying to not use built in functions. sorry, i'll edit question

Comment: @ObeseOctopus you will use only 2 number or more? And what kind of sorting do you prefer?